# C++ Swapping Values By Reference

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, function-pointers

I came across a C++ code snippet in my exams which was quite confusing (at least for me). I tried to analyze it but there is something that I am unable to understand. The code is written below:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int* doMagic(int *p, int *q)
{
    int* t = new int();
    t = p;
    p = q;
    q = t;
    return t;
}

int main()
{
    int p = 5, q = 10;
    int *t = NULL;
    t = doMagic(&p, &q);
    cout<<"p = "<<p<<endl;
    cout<<"q = "<<q<<endl;
    cout<<"t = "<<*t<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
p = 5
q = 10
t = 5
```

Now my question is that when the values were passed by reference to `doMagic` function why weren't the values swapped in it.

Help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You do not use any reference in your code. And to do swap using pointers you should change *pointee* values, not pointers themselves. I suggest you ditch your current learning source and get [a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to learn C++.

Comment: `doMagic` takes its arguments by *pointer*, *not* by reference. You are swapping pointers, not what the pointers point to.

Comment: Also; look up [std::swap](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap). Swapping two values efficiently is a *solved* problem. There's no need for you to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: pointers are passed by value, most stuff going on in `doMagic` has no effect

Comment: Also; remember that C++ is a *context sensitive* language. `&` means different things in different contexts. In some contexts it means "reference", in others it means "address of".

Comment: @JesperJuhl Firstly, I mentioned that I came across this question in the exam so I am not reinventing the wheel & Secondly we are swapping the address of `p` & `q` so the values should also be swapped naturally.

Comment: @Gingitsune you are just swapping the values/addresses stored in some function-local variables (`p`, `q` & `t` are all *function-local* variables, all holding an address of something and you are just swapping addresses between variables). That doesn't swap what they point to.

Comment: oh, I understand ... thanks, mate

Comment: I hope the question was something like "find all the problems in this code", because it's horrible.

Comment: `int *t = NULL;` - better --> `int *t = nullptr;`

Comment: Btw; you do know that `endl` flushes the stream, right? If you just want a newline, then `'\n'` is more efficient for the first printouts until you *really* also want a flush. Doesn't matter for a trivial program, but, I've seen pointless flushes seriously degrade performance in real life programs. Don't do more work than you intend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code nothing gets passed by reference.

Some pointer values (`&p`, `&q`) get passed by value.

Because they were passed by value, they were stored into new variables in `doMagic` called `p` and `q`. The new variables were then swapped. The value `&p` was returned and stored in `main`'s variable `t`.

Also, some memory was leaked, because an `int` was created with `new` and was never destroyed with `delete`.

Answer (score 3):

The variables `p` and `p` in `doMagic` are local to the function. Any changes made to those variables are made locally in the function. They don't change anything in the calling function.

You can rename those variables to `x` and `y` without changing the function's behavior. That will also be a reminder that the names in `main` and the name in `doMagic` are separate and independent.

You can swap the values in `doMagic` by swapping the values of the objects the pointers point to:

```
void doMagic(int *p, int *q)
{
    int t = *p;
    *p = *q;
    *q = t;
}
```

although it is idiomatically better C++ to use references

```
void doMagic(int& p, int& q)
{
    int t = p;
    p = q;
    q = t;
}
```

Then, the function can be called from `main` as:

```
doMagic(p, q);
```

Having said that, if you don't intend to do anything more in the function, you should use `std::swap` instead. There is nothing to gain by defining a function in user space that duplicates the functionality of a standard library function.

Comment: "althoug it is idiomatically better C++ to use references" - or just `std::swap` in the first place.